# expandablelistview disappear when group collapse

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to use expandablelistview in my android app, the problem is that when I click a EXPANDED group the whole expandablelistview disappear, does anyone had the same problem and knows how to fix it?

my getChildrenCount & getGroupCount methoods:

```
      @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {

        return super.getGroupCount();
    }
```

Comment: Did you implement the method `getGroupCount` and `getChildrenCount`? sound like the count is change to 0 so your whole list contain NO items-> it disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by overriding the onCollpse() methood & notifyDataSetInvalidated() in it:

```
    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {

        notifyDataSetInvalidated();

    }
```